# Android AVD not launching

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to develop android applications. Initially the AVD used to run fine but when I launched it today, it just did not load. It just kept showing the blank screen with the word ANDROID glowing. I waited for quite a couple of minutes but it did not start. I even reinstalled my sdk but still no progress. 
I am using Windows 7(32 bit) with 4 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check virtual devices characteristics of your device created, sometimes if you choose a big resolution it doesn´t wokrs. [check this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-virtual-device-creation--mobile-12350). 
also, I recommend you to use Android studio because eclipse is no longer used